# Disable DoubleClick Tag When Embedded YouTube Video Loads

Tags: cookies, double-click-advertising

My website is failing a cookie policy scan because the DoubleClick Tag is loaded when an embedded YouTube video is displayed on my web page. I have disabled "data collection" in my Google Analytics account but the DoubleClick tag still loads. As the DoubleClick tag is originating from embedded YouTube video I don't know how to disable the DoubleClick tag. I have also added "https://www.youtube-nocookie...." URL to the video link which does prevent information from being sent via DoubleClick but does not prevent the DoubleClick tag from loading, which fails the scan. Is there a way to disable the DoubleClic tag from loading through embedded YouTube video ().

Answer (score 1):

So here's youtube's answer on it. I think the best way is probably to just use your own player loading up the youtube video:

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/132596?hl=en